# How to get this JSON Data

Tags: php, json

Hello friends I am trying reading this json in php but I don´t get to extract the data correctly

I try this and works

```
echo $jsonencode->extractordata->url;
echo $jsonencode->extractordata->resourceid;
```

I want to extract information that it is in data array I try this but it doesn´t work It show me error

```
echo $jsonencode->extractordata->data->group->hora;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the proper way to traverse your JSON:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json);

if (empty($data->extractorData->data)) {
  die("Invalid data\n");
}

foreach ($data->extractorData->data as $d) {
  if (!is_array($d->group) || !is_array($d->group))
    continue;

  foreach ($d->group as $group) {
    if (!isset($group->Hora) || !is_array($group->Hora))
      continue;

    foreach ($group->Hora as $hora) {
      if (!isset($hora->text))
        continue;

      echo "$hora->text\n";
    }
  }
}
```

*Sample Output*

```
01:00 CET
01:30 CET
01:30 CET
02:00 CET
02:30 CET
04:30 CET
...
```

Comment: Thanks it´s work perfect I only had to change this $jsondecode->result->extractordata thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
$jsonencode->extractorData->data[0]->group[0]->Hora
```

The "data" property is an array.

Comment: @htmlpower To be more precise, you would do `echo $jsonencode->extractorData->data[0]->group[0]->Hora[0]->text;`